# Javascript : exporting several arrays to specific excel positions

Tags: javascript, excel, csv

I need to export several arrays, that dont have the same header, into one single excel or csv file.
I have checked Alasql which provide an excel export for one array and ng-csv, which seems to have the same limitation.
What I need to do is simple : write arrays on specific excel slot.
Do you know a way to do that ? 
I am using angular.

Thank you.